# How can one use Beautiful Soup to get information from all the sub url's under a certain url?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My use case is trying to get all the emails from suburls like https://blueprint.uchicago.edu/organization/acacouncil under a parent url: https://blueprint.uchicago.edu/organizations.

I know the general form of the email will be xyz@xyz.com, so locating the email for a single url is easy enough. But when it comes to doing that for all the suburls I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Start by thinking about how you would have to do it manually, in the web browser. Then think about ways of automating that process. Don't expect a library to automatically solve the whole problem and don't ask StackOverflow to write your code for you. Once you come up with a solution, this is the right place to ask for help to get your code to work, if you're having problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sense in using beautifulsoup here as you can fetch the data directly from the api. First you'll need to know how many organizations there are so that you can use that in the query. Then by grabbing the `'WebsiteKey'` or the organization `id`, you can iterate through the api to pull the emails. You can store in a dictionary, table, print out, etc. Not sure what you really want as the output.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://blueprint.uchicago.edu/api/discovery/search/organizations'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {
'orderBy[0]': 'UpperName asc',
'top': '',
'filter':'',
'query':'' ,
'skip': '0'}
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()

totalCount = data['@odata.count']
payload = {
'orderBy[0]': 'UpperName asc',
'top': '%s' %totalCount,
'filter':'',
'query':'' ,
'skip': '0'}


data = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()

organizations = {}
for each in data['value']:
    organizations[each['Name']] = {'id':each['Id'], 'WebsiteKey':each['WebsiteKey']}




emails = {}
for name, each in organizations.items():
    websiteKey = each['WebsiteKey']
    org_id = each['id']

    url = 'https://blueprint.uchicago.edu/api/discovery/organization/bykey/%s' %websiteKey
    data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    emails[name] = data['email']
    print('%-70s: %s' %(name, data['email']))

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(emails.keys(), emails.values())), columns=['Organization','Email'])
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
{'A Cappella Council': 'uchicagoacappella@gmail.com', 'ACLU University of Chicago Law Chapter': 'dhbabrams@uchicago.edu', 'Active Minds at the University of Chicago': 'activemindsuchicago@gmail.com', 'African and Caribbean Student Association': 'cvleito@uchicago.edu', 'Aikido Kokikai': 'nahmadc@uchicago.edu', 'Alpha Kappa Psi': 'edwardchang@uchicago.edu', 'Alpha Phi Omega': 'uchi.apo.president@gmail.com', 'American Civil Liberties Union at University of Chicago': 'acluboard@lists.uchicago.edu', 'American Constitution Society': 'acs@law.uchicago.edu', 'American Medical Student Association': None, 'American Red Cross of University of Chicago': 'rkhouri@uchicago.edu', 'Amnesty International': 'eckere@uchicago.edu', 'Animal Legal Defense Fund - The University of Chicago Law School': 'ntschepik@uchicago.edu', 'Animal Welfare Society': 'petrucci@uchicago.edu', 'Anthropology Students Association': 'frevelolarotta@uchicago.edu', 'Apsara': 'uchicagoapsara@gmail.com', 'Arab Student Association': 'malakarafa@uchicago.edu', ...}
```

Comment: Oh wow, how did you find the api url?
I'm trying to do a similar thing for UT Austin organizations:
https://utexas.campuslabs.com/engage/organizations

Comment: And output looking for csv, which seems to be pretty straightforward using Python's built-in csv library (import csv)

Comment: If you open Dev Tools (Ctrl-Shft-I) and look at the Network tab --> XHR. Also, just use pandas to write to csv. I'll update the code

Comment: Wow, incredible. Thank you so much. I looked at Network -> XHR for the UT Austin orgs, and it looks like there are five different api urls. I'm guessing it's the second one? (https://utexas.campuslabs.com/engage/api/discovery/search/organizations)

Comment: Use the "preview" tab to see what it returns. Then you can narrow down to which one you want

Comment: I believe it is that url, it's pretty similar in format to the UChicago one. But it seems to not be working, strangely enough.
I'm changing the url on line 4 to: https://utexas.campuslabs.com/engage/api/discovery/search/organizations, and line 37 to url = 'https://utexas.campuslabs.com/engage/api/discovery/search/organizations/bykey/%s' % websiteKey

Comment: oh ok. ya i see what you mean. ya it looks similar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207190/discussion-between-hojung-kim-and-chitown88).